# Convert String with special characters

Tags: java

`String descriptionEscaped = "Domnul Florin C&icirc;ţu afirmă"`

=>

`String descriptionEscaped = "Domnul Florin Cîţu afirmă, sâmbătă"`

Is there a way to do this ?
(Sorry for the confusing title of question)

Comment: [`StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(String)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeHtml4-java.lang.String-)

Comment: It work, thanks a lot!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You know a method with I can remove the double quotes from a string ?

Comment: `System.out.println("\"Yes\"".replaceAll("\"", ""));`

Comment: I know this, I think that exist similar method with above one, just for consistency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following is helping you to convert special characters

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String descriptionEscaped = "Domnul Florin C&icirc;ţu afirmă";
    descriptionEscaped = 
  StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(descriptionEscaped);
    System.out.println(descriptionEscaped);
}
```